# Regex to remove characters and supplied words

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex that will allow only alphanumeric characters AND also remove certain full-words.

Example:

Input string: **this-is-johny-bravo's-grand-dad**

Result string: **johny-bravos-dad**

Words/characters to replace by an empty string: this,is,',grand

Here is what I have so far:

```
var input = "this-is-johny-bravo's-grand-dad";
var regex = new Regex(@"([^a-z0-9\-][\b(this|is|grand)\b]?)");
var result = regex.Replace(input, "");
```

The result seems to not have the apostrophe but unfortunately still includes the rejected full-words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to add the character class to alternation:

```
new Regex(@"\b(this|is|grand)\b-?|[^a-z0-9-]");
```

Comment: +1 That's probably more to the intent of the OP than mine. :)

Comment: (though there's still a syntax error in the expression and it does not remove the superfluous dashes)

Comment: Looks good, I just had to remove the extra ')' bracket you have. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomalak Yeah, I need to do something about the extra dashes.

Comment: @Tomalak Oops. Fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh and that in my answer is not meant to be an expression but merely the explanation block of the expression above it. It does not need `(?x)` ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak Oh! Sorry for that ;)

Comment: Even better now. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 3):

Your expression is too complicated. Try

```
\b(this|is|grand|')\b-?
```

Also, and that is the root cause of your problem: Character classes are not for alternation. This `[\b(this|is|grand)\b]` is syntactically equivalent to this `[()adghinrst|]`.

Thinking about it, you probably want this:

```
(\b(this|is|grand)\b|[^a-z0-9-])-?
```

Break-down:

```
(                          # group 1
    \b(this|is|grand)\b    #   any of these words
    |                      #   or 
    [^a-z0-9-]             #   any character except one of these
)                          # end group 1
-?                         # optional dash at the end
```

Comment: Will word boundary work for `'`? I mean I'm not sure about this. Else this is nice shortened version.

Comment: @Rohit Yes, by accident. Word boundaries work both ways, one immediately occurs before the `'` (the end of the word `"bravo"`) and one follows (the beginning of the word `"s"`). But it's not what the OP *meant*, so forget the short version and take the longer one.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation block, it really helps understand the syntax.